# What is the best way to covert horizontally organized cards to be vertically stacked in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I am creating an agile resource planner. I have found a way to generate a 'Summary' from a dataset in my 'Breakout' which summarizes my resources by sprint.

**Issue:**
The issue is that the only way I could get this to generate was to use a horizontal layout.

**Attempted Solutions:**
To remedy this I used nested ARRAYFORMULA()s to stack the sprints in a vertical layout and used FILTER() to remove all of the blank cells.

**Issues with Attempted Solution:**
The issue with my solution is that I always need to know how many sprints I am planning because if my ARRAYFORMULA() detects a blank range it will give me an error. Additionally, my formula is incredibly long and I have less ability to visually format my data.

Reference Worksheet: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HiRkMiRBzT-p6_7hQHXHPbA3eGB5jH88LBpcSR9P0TM/edit?usp=sharing)

Appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks,
Karl

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `TRANSPOSE`? The function which transposes ROWS to COLUMNS and vice versa.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment! Sadly, because of the schema of the data I'm trying working with I don't know if I can use TRANSPOSE(). I definitely can't out of the box standalone.